# Can my site's administrators bypass required profile fields during user creation?

Tags: users

I have two separate roles on my site, one for regular users, and one for site administrators.

The regular users must fill out more details about themselves than I need admins to do, such as name, gender and address.

How can I allow the site administrator to create new site administrators without needing to fill out these extra profile fields?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: separate this registration form from Drupal registration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only easy way I can think of is to make this fields not required. Then the admins can leave it empty.

I'd just let the Admins enter the extra data, even if you don't really need it. Admins are specially trust worthy users. It's not likely that you have a lot of them.

If you must: Create your own form using [Drupa FAPI](http://drupal.org/node/751826) and create a new user by calling [user_save](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_save/7) in the submit function.

Answer (score 0):

Use the module [profile2_regpath](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) and provide different paths for each profile type.

Ensure that:

```
Show on all user account registration forms.
If selected, fields for this profile type will be added to the core user registration page and the administrative add user page.
```

Is unchecked.